# proof using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality 5

Tags: inequality

[image]

In the proof i understood the first line but i dont know what happens suddenly on the second line.Please explain this.Thank you

Comment: Can you send me a link to that problem?

Comment: here is the download link of that document.https://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvNC9kLzNkMTI2NmUxODY2ODM2OThiZWIyMDI3NTg3OTk0MzNhOTIxYzgw&rn=UHJvYmxlbXMgdXNpbmcgQ2F1Y2h5LVNjaHdhcnouZG9j

Comment: i have found the link yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we perform the multiplication on the summands, we get
$$a(5a+b+9c)=5a^2 +ab+9ca$$
Now we add them cyclically:
$$\sum_{cyc} a(5a+b+9c) \ =\ 5a^2 +5b^2 +5c^2 +10ab+10bc+10ca\ =\ 5(a+b+c)^2 $$

Comment: got it thanks alot.Can you explain the next line too,please,how 5/16 came?

Comment: Both sides of the original inequality are squared, so the constant there becomes $25/16$ and now we introduced a $5$, if we divide both sides by $5$, we arrive to the constant $5/16$.

Comment: oh thanks for your answer.just one more question,In the proof we introduced (5a+b+9c),while doing such proofs how do we know what to introduce?

Comment: well i guess,we have to consider whats on right side and try to make the same by adding cyclically